# Status bar in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, statusbar

```
<StatusBar  Height="20" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="statusBar1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="1533" Background="AntiqueWhite">
        <TextBlock >HName:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="hname" Text="{Binding Path=CHost}"></TextBlock>
        <Separator/>
        <TextBlock >P:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="p" Text="{Binding Path=CPort, TargetNullValue=6130,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        <Separator/>
        <TextBlock Name="cstatus">CStatus:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CoStatus" Text="{Binding Path=CStatus, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        <Separator/>
        <TextBlock AllowDrop="False" Name="sock1">CSock:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CoName" Text="{Binding Path=CoName,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>

        <Separator x:Name="seperator1" Margin="520,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock >HName:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="hname1" Text="{Binding Path=CHost1}"></TextBlock>
        <Separator/>
        <TextBlock >P:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="p1" Text="{Binding Path=CPort, TargetNullValue=6130,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        <Separator/>
        <TextBlock Name="cstatus1">CStatus:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CStatus1" Text="{Binding Path=CStatus1, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        <Separator/>
        <TextBlock AllowDrop="False" Name="sock2">Sock1:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CoName1" Text="{Binding Path=CoName1,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
    </StatusBar>
```

I have added this status bar in my main window and placed bottom of my screen. I have control inside that to show some text with value.

I have to show information of Hname, P, CStatus and sock for two different client on same status bar of main window.

So I have used    for making space between them.

But what I want when My application first time launch  after  all information should not be visible when I'm connect my second client then this part come but there should be enough space between them so that Screen look good.

Width and height of  status  bar is 1533 and 20 respectively. I tried to put two child status bar for two different client on status bar but  SomeHow It didn't work. Please suggest how to do this

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use grid inside the statusbar like this:

```
<StatusBar HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                 ...
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <!-- Content goes here using the grid -->
         <Grid/>
      <StatusBarItem/>
 <StatusBar/>
```

Or use an itemtemplate for the status bar like this:

```
<StatusBar Height="40">
    <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>

    <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
    <!-- content... -->
    </StatusBarItem>

    <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
    <!-- content -->
    </StatusBarItem>

    <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2" Visibility="{Binding IsSomePropertyVisible, Converter={StaticResrouce BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <!-- content -->
    </StatusBarItem>
     ....
 </StatusBar>
```

Use a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine what parts of your statusbar that should be visible or not. Beware of setting explicit sizes now! Typically you want some property that's a bool which tells if the user is logged in or not, and just bind to that property and use a BooleanToVisbilityConverter.

You may also dump the template for the control and disassemble it, to see how it works internally.

Hope it helps,

Cheers

Stian